# Deterministic multifractal measure with quadratic singular spectrum?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, gaussian, fractals

For a non-negative locally finite measure $\mu$ on a bounded metric space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B})$, its local Holder exponent $f(x)$ is defined as $$f(x)=\lim_{r\downarrow 0}\frac{\mu(B(x,r))}{\log r}$$
whenever it exists. Its singular spectrum is then defined as $$d_{\mu}(\alpha)=\mathrm{dim}_{\mathcal{H}}(\{x\in\Omega:f(x)=\alpha\}),$$
where $\mathrm{dim}_{\mathcal{H}}$ is the Hausdorff dimension.

For $\mu$ supported on a pure fractal, $d_{\mu}(\alpha)$ is a delta function on its fractal dimension. When it is not a delta function, it is considered as a multifractal measure.

Now, here is my problem. I'm reading Gaussian multiplicative chaos, and it has a singular spectrum of the form almost surely $$d_{GMC}(\alpha)=d-(a-b\alpha)^2,\quad\alpha\in[\alpha_{\min},\alpha_{\max}],$$ and the quadratic form comes from the Gaussian nature.

My question is:

> Can we define a deterministic measure $\mu$ such that $d_{\mu}(\alpha)$ has the form $(aq-bq^2+c)\vee 0$ with some $a,b,c>0$?

I think this can also serve as a prototype of understanding Gaussian multifractal measure.